# Ford Figo 2012 dash board low fuel problem

Tags: ford, diesel, figo

I am using 2012 Ford Figo Diesel Model and currently I am getting an error in my dashboard like low fuel warning even though diesel tank having 1/2 of its capacity.  Due to that its not allowing to make the ENGINE ON at some times not all times. Given to Authorized ford service centre and they told me the relay unit was gone and they replaced it, still the problem continues.... Now I don't have reliable in my car for starting purpose... Is there any permanent solution?

Comment: Personally, I'd take it back to the service center and tell them it's not fixed.  Do you still have the old "relay unit"?

Comment: Something is not reading reliable here, either the gauge, or the light.  You seem to believe it is the light that is malfunctioning, is it possible it is the gauge that is not reading correctly and you are actually low on fuel?  The light should not stop the car from starting.

Comment: How are you confirming the tank is actually at half capacity?  Are you relying on the gauge?